Nginx Ingress in Kubernetes 502 Bad Gateway Error when trying to access frontend
I have a linux vm with k3s installed, and installed a Nginx-Ingress controller. I’m facing an issue while setting up the Nginx Ingress controller in my Kubernetes cluster. My goal is to setup https in the frontend, but I keep encountering a persistent 502 Bad Gateway error when accessing my application via the Ingress URL (app.192.168.[something].nip.io).
These are the details of the frontend service. (kubectl describe svc)
These are all the pods.
The results of (kubectl get svc -o wide)
The error logs of the Ingress-NginX shows:
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while conencting to upstream, client: 192.168.223.229, server: app.192.168.[something].nip.io, request:
"GET / HTTP/ 2.0", upstream:  "http://10.43.141.56:3000/", host: "app.192.168.[something].nip.io"

The frontend runs, the pod is up, I'm not sure where to go from here.
The Ingress resource:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - secretName: dailygrind-tls
    hosts:
    - app.192.168.[something].nip.io
  rules:
  - host: app.192.168.[something].nip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend
            port:
              number: 3000


Please note that service frontend located in default namespace is LoadBalancer type and I think it should be ClusterIP since you don't want to publicly expose your service and then connect to it via ingress.

Thank you for the comment! Is this a side-recommendation, or could this also be causing the issue?

I think this can cause the issue since when you connect you traffic will go like LoadBalancer -> Ingress nginx -> Service with external endpoint -> Application.
I am not sure but for me connection between ingress and external service can cause some routing problems.

Doesn't work sadly, but if I, within the vm, use curl http://frontend:3000 it says Could not resolve host: frontend.
Could this indicate an issue, since in the ingress-resource it's referring to service-name frontend, so it might not be able to reach it? I don't know what that could be causing though.

since if I use the frontend's clusterIP to curl, it outputs the Vite homepage which is correct.

i had the same issue where one deployment was working in one k8s cluster but not in the other.
then i found this issue on github
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6110
setting nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true" resolved the issue in my case.
sadly i had this issue with multiple services, which also came from official helm charts, so i suppose it is some global settings problem, i still have to figure out.
hope this helps
